# How do you set an attribute when creating an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to set an attribute on an object that I am creating.  I feel like this should work:

```
 def create
    @album = Album.new(params[:album])
    @album.user = current_user

    if @album.save
       flash[:notice] = 'Album was successfully created for ' + current_user.login + '.'
       redirect_to albums_url 
    else
       render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

But it seems to ignore the assignment to the `user` field.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your model relationships are set up correctly*, it's better to do:

```
@album = current_user.albums.build(params[:album])
```

—This will correctly populate the `user_id` field for the new album to the ID of the current user.

---

*Something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  .
  .
  .
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  .
  .
  .
end
```

Comment: Yes, I do have the class hierarchy set up correctly. So, I should this in place of the call to Album.new?  When I try that, I get undefined method `build' for #<User:0x353c3a4>

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in my code which I've corrected now. The build method is on the User's albums array. That scopes the new album to the albums belonging to that user i.e. populates the user_id field of the new album.

Answer (score 1):

Did your Album migration or does your album model reference a user_id or a relationship to user?

If not, the database won't save that information even if you assign it.

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing.  I forgot to run the migration script to set up that relationship in the database.  Thanks!