# how to display vendor_id for my reviews by a given user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to write a simple application and I am stumped!

Here is what I have as a view for users/show/1:

```
<p>
  <b>User:</b>
  <%=h @user.login %>
</p>

    <% if @user.reviews.empty? %>
        No Analyst Reports yet
    <% else %>
        <% for review in @user.reviews %>
            <%= review.vendor_id %><%= review.summary %><br />
            <hr class="span-5" />

        <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I created a relationship where user :has_many reviews and vendor :has_many reviews

So I assume that there should be a value for review.vendor_id, where vendor_id is just automatically created and can be displayed.

Thank you :)

Here is my Reviews model:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Actually this has been solved, I now need to go through the for-loop and display attributes of vendor....see my other question please!  Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/764033/how-can-i-pass-a-value-between-controllers-new-create-in-ror ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your review model have the corresponding
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :vendor
 - ?

Also, when a review is created, have you checked that the vendor_id is filled?
check this question: 
[How do you set an attribute when creating an ActiveRecord object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753379/how-do-you-set-an-attribute-when-creating-an-activerecord-object)

Comment: Yes, to both!  I have a belongs to :user and belongs_to :vendor
It appears that the database is in fact storing the vendor_id value in each review....but how do I extract the vendor name and vendor id?

Comment: <%=h review.vendor.id %>
<%=h review.vendor.name %>